# How to extract specific data from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, extract

My string will always come back in the following format, where the numbers represent the changing variables that I need to target:

```
params:string = "a random description here followed by a space and then this #gruser4upload #gruser15cat #gruser23camp"
```

How can I extract the numbers?

Given the string above, I would need to achieve the following results:

```
upload = 4
cat = 15
camp = 23
```

I have tried using a method like the following, however it will not work due to the fact that `#gruser` exists in all three of my targets.

```
let upload = params.substring(
              params.lastIndexOf("#gruser") + 1, 
              params.lastIndexOf("upload")
            );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to capture digits followed by alphabetical characters, then extract each group:

```js
const params = "a random description here followed by a space and then this #gruser4upload #gruser15cat #gruser23camp";
let match;
const re = /(\d+)([a-z]+)/gi;
while (match = re.exec(params)) {
  console.log(match[1] + ' : ' + match[2]);
}
```

Comment: dude ... THANK YOU ... amazing! you are a rock star.